# Problems with node path from bash scripts

Tags: bash, path, node.js

I'm writing a script which at one point starts a simple node.js based website:

```
cd ../ap-site/ && npm start
```

When I run the above command from terminal there is no problem, but when run from my script I get:

```
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

I'm using [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to manage node versions currently, so I tried adding `nvm use 8.8.1` to my `~/.bashrc` and then sourcing the file in my script directly:

```
source /home/rescue/.bashrc
cd ../ap-site/ && npm start
```

I also tried using `which npm` in terminal and using the resulting path directly like:

```
cd ../ap-site/ && /home/rescue/.nvm/v8.8.1/bin/npm start
```

But I got the same result.

Any ideas on how I can debug the situation and run node projects from my bash script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Apologies for posting the question and answer so quickly, but maybe it will be useful for someone.*

Though I was sourcing bash `nvm` didn't seem to load, despite it being in my `.bashrc` file.

Instead of sourcing my `.bashrc` I setup `nvm` at the top of the script directly:

```
export NVM_DIR="/home/rescue/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
nvm use 8.8.1
```

Once I did this my `npm` commands started working.

*I'm still not sure why sourcing `.bashrc` didn't work as expected, since it contains the same 3 lines of code.*

It might be relevant that the script is always run with `sudo`?